# Visual Studio IDE Doesn't Recognize EJS Variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, express, ejs

I am making a project in Nodejs with the express framework I am using EJS as a template engine, I use **Visual Studio** as an IDE.

I have a problem while using **EJS** variable in the same ejs file, it renders correctly and works perfectly but Visual Studio marks it an error at the syntax

Is there any Tools or Extensions Features available, To overcome this issue

> Error shown in IDE

[image]

**Any one please help in solving this error in Visual Studio.**

Answer (score 1):

Right-click any given *.ejs file, and Select "Open With". In the dialog that opens, select "HTML (Web Forms) Editor" and select it as default.

Now, when you open your EJS files, you will get syntax highlighting and intellisense for your HTML. This does not give you support for EJS Code snippets, but will not throw errors.

Comment: Thanks. Now the error disappeared, But as you said syntax highlighting and IntelliSense still doesn't work for EJS Code. If you come across any solution, please share.

Comment: Sure... I will update. Also, please have an eye on Visual Studio release notes too.